# Why docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is empty?

Tags: docker, percona

I m trying to import MySQL file using Docker. Below is the code snippet.

```
mysql_testttt:
image: percona:5.7.22
container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}mysqleetestttt"
volumes:
  - /mysql/mysql_test:/var/lib/mysql:Z
  - /db_dumps/test:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: d8_test
  MYSQL_USER: d8
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: d8
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: d8root
restart: always
networks:
  - front
```

Run docker-compose up -d. Command run successfully. But inside this new container, docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder show empty. Even db is empty. So I m confused why this is happening. Why my db is not getting imported?

Comment: Did you tried to run this image with the same setting on CLI with `docker run ...`? 
And even when it sounds to easy: please check if your path is correct and contains the files (my own experience... )

Comment: (As you’ve written it the dump must be underneath a directory named `/db_dumps` in the root directory of your host system, not your home directory or the directory with the `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Comment: @wie i have checked each path but still no success.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tired that too. Still the database is not getting loaded. Well the data under mysql_test is getting copied correctly. But db_dumps are not getting copied.

Comment: @Sudha a little late but can you try with `- /db_dumps/test:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. (mind the `/` at last)